# How can I get multiple bootstrap cols in 1 row without nesting?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create this grid with bootstrap:

[image]

I can easily create the first row no problem using cols. It would be simple enough to create a second row, however, the entire grid has a drop shadow, so even when I create a second row and just bump it up, I cant create a drop shadow under the entire grid.

I have tried nesting other cols inside the row but it doesn't work well since the columns are not the same width above and below.

Here is what I have so far: https://jsfiddle.net/5nk28tm0/

Using

```
display: flex;
padding-top:120px
padding-bottom:100px;
```

to keep the columns all the same height. Just need to add another row without losing the drop shadow ability. Not sure what to try from here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because the columns each have a varying height, hence the elements are not in proper order. If you use the CSS below, you can restrict the minimum height and all the elements will align accordingly.

```
.row > div {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```css
.home-testimonial {
  .row {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    box-shadow: 15px 10px 50px #e3e3e3;
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    align-content: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 120px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    color: #333e48;
  }
  .testimonial-body {
    padding-left: 40px;
    padding-right: 40px;
  }
}

.row > div {
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="home-testimonial">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-2 bg-success">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="testimonial-body">
        Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="testimonial-body">
        Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 bg-success">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="testimonial-body">
        Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="testimonial-body">
        Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 bg-success">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="testimonial-body">
        Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      <p class="testimonial-body">
        Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      Placeholder text here. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x44">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this didn't seem to help. This created one big long row for me without stacking them.

Comment: @becca The columns were set for small screen, I adjusted for extra small screen, can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth checking out CSS Grid for this layout.